# How can I use special character in a string?

Tags: objective-c

i have this IBAction, and i want to send this message :
**Toggle "Program Time"**, but this message contain **""**
my problem is how to use "" in a string?

my code :

```
-(IBAction)sendToggleTime{
[connection SendCode:@"Toggle Program Time"];}
```

and i want :

```
-(IBAction)sendToggleTime{
[connection SendCode:@"Toggle "Program Time""];}
```

Comment: This is, BTW, first week stuff.  You should get a "C for dummies" book and study it to pick up the basics.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **escape** the quotes with a `\`

This removes the special functionality of the succeeding character.

```
-(IBAction)sendToggleTime{
[connection SendCode:@"Toggle \"Program Time\""];}
```

Answer (score 0):

use backslashes like \" Toggle program title\"

Comment: https://www.google.lk/search?q=objective+c+escape+characters&aq=0&oq=objective+cescape+&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3.9164j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Not quite.  The second backslash is on the wrong side of the quote.